# Why is 'this.props.navigation' unavailable to screen component?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a drawer navigator that has a stack navigator nested inside it as one of the screen options. I have no issues navigating to any screens in the drawer, but when I try to navigate to another screen in the stack navigator, I dont have access to `this.props.navigation`. Im confused because the screen is declared in my navigator setup.

AppNavigator:

```
// all imports

const InboxStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Inbox: {
      screen: HomeScreen
    },
    Conversation: {
      screen: ConversationScreen
    }
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "Inbox"
  }
);

const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Inbox: InboxStack,
    Second: { screen: SecondScreen },
    Third: { screen: ThirdScreen }
  },
  {
    drawerPosition: "left",
    initialRouteName: "Inbox",
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: "Drawer Navigator Header",
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "blue"
      },
      headerLeft: <Text onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>Menu</Text>
    })
  }
);

const WrapperStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  drawerNav: MainNavigator
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      App: WrapperStackNavigator,
      Login: LoginScreen,
      Register: RegisterScreen
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "AuthLoading"
    }
  )
);

export default AppContainer;
```

utilization of navigation prop in ConversationScreen:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { loadConversation } from "../actions";
import MessagesList from "../components/MessagesList.js";

class ConversationScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadConversation();
  }

  loadConversation() {
    this.props.loadConversation(
      this.props.navigation.state.params.convoId // this works!
      this.props.navigation.getParams("convoId") // this does not :(
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Text>Conversation screen</Text>
        <MessagesList messages={this.props.messages} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({ conversation, auth }) => {
  const { messages } = conversation;
  const { user } = auth;
  return { messages, user };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loadConversation
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ConversationScreen);
```

The issue exists with `ConversationScreen`, I dont have access to the navigation prop, but docs say if its declared in the navigator it should be be passed the navigation prop. Every call using `this.props.navigation` errors with `... is not a function`, `... is undefined`
`...` being `this.props.navigation.navigate`, `this.props.navigation.getParams`, etc

Comment: Are you sure `navigation` prop is undefined? Where is `this.props.loadConversation` coming from? I think `loadConversation` is undefined.

Comment: `loadConversation` is a an action dispatched to my reducer, there's no issue with it, because if I put a dummie argument it works no errors. the exact error: `TypeError: this.props.navigation.getParams is not a function. (In 'this.props.navigation.getParams("convoId")', 'this.props.navigation.getParams' is undefined)`

Comment: How are you routing to `ConversationScreen`?

Comment: by passing `this.props.navigation` as a prop to a component inside the "Home" route inside the `InboxStack` with `this.props.navigation.navigate("Conversation", {convoId: this.props.convoId});`

Comment: Can you post the full code for your `ConversationScreen`? It's hard to know what's going on without the code

Comment: While I found a way to achieve my goal (see edit), I still dont know why `this.props.navigation.getParams()` was coming up undefined

Answer (score 0):

After checking the props object through `alert(this.props)` I verified I had access to the navigation object, even though it appeared to be undefined, ultimately using

```
componentDidMount() {
   loadConversation() {
    this.props.loadConversation(
      this.props.navigation.state.params.convoId
    );
   }
 }
```

This got me where I needed to be. although it would have been nice to just use `this.props.navigation.getParams()`